# Taking keyboard input while using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a simple tkinter GUI app, and what I want to do is that the user enters some value in an entry box and presses enter and I take that data. So for that I used Keyboard module's read_key() function.
So bacically:

```
key = ''
while key != 'enter':
    key = keyboard.read_key()
data = entrybox.get()
```

However when this happens tkinter errors out saying its not responding. I tried other options but they didn't really work. Am I doing something wrong or is there an alternative for this?

Comment: why not use `entrybox.bind('<Return>', someFun)`

Comment: I could use this, but is there anyway to pause the program until I invoke it? Also, I need the GUI not to be stopped during this time.

Comment: I didn't quite get you. `bind` method will not stop the GUI.

Comment: Nvm that, is it possible to wait until its invoked? Like print("Enter age") wait till invoked print("Age is, age)

Comment: wait until the return key is pressed?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: maybe you can bind the return key to a function and check if it is invoked. I can't comment further on that as I have no clue what you are trying. I must warn you that pausing the GUI for a long time might lead to crashes.